# How to update data using listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to update a data using list box.

Record shows in ListBox(lstDisplay),when I clicked on a single record, those record will display in the textfield, where I can start to edit them.

And then I have to click Save to save the changes,however the only data that is changing is the last name column.

Before update:
[image]

After update: 
[image]

please see my code

```
Dim wks As Integer
Dim i As Integer
wks = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))
For i = 2 To wks
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value = Me.txtSearch.Text Then
        Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = Me.txtLname.Text
        Sheet1.Cells(i, "C").Value = Me.txtFname.Text
        Sheet1.Cells(i, "D").Value = Me.cmbCourse.Text
        Sheet1.Cells(i, "E").Value = Me.cmbYear.Text
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Can you show the code that fills the fields on the left (first name, last name etc.) and how is it called? Also, can you show if you have any worksheet events in your sheet? Your loop to fill the sheet looks fine, but given the problem it looks like that when the sheet gets updated with `Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = Me.txtLname.Text`, the form gets reloaded with the old data still existing in the sheet.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ what do you mean by "Can you show the code that fills the fields on the left (first name, last name etc.) and how is it called? "
?

Comment: When you open this form, you have a ListBox reading from the sheet and showing the information in there. You said that when you click on one line, you get the form on the left filled with the information of that line, so that you can modify them, and then when you click on Update Info, you get them written in the sheet. I would like to see the code which handles these two events.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ how do i do it??, how do i put the code here??

Comment: Exactly as you copied pasted the code snippet above :)